# Haar training with small samples

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, object-detection, haar-classifier

Please can anyone help with where I can get Haar training files that use small samples such as 5? I have downloaded a couple but one is giving me error messages while the second require 1000 samples.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Little samples is not how it is designed to work with. Almost all the algorithms that lets us do classification need a large amount of training samples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you think will be a fair number of samples for any classification algorithm?

Comment: The same words, you'll need a large amount of samples to train, whatever if it's a fair number or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to detect. If you want to detect a logo and you have a clean image of a logo, you can create many training samples out of it by adding noise, changing contrast and brightness, rotating, distorting, etc. OpenCV's Haar training module supports this, so it won't be hard.
This is called data augmentation. But if you want to detect faces, data augmentation alone won't be enough. 
Creating a rule-based system by observing the few samples that you have works best for this situation, if what you want to detect is a natural object. 
I can add additional links to this answer, pointing to sample code, if you can provide more details.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I will appreciate additional links to the answer. Assuming I want to detect a peanut in a scene with other objects.

Comment: I have detected cat faces at a good rate by training with only 100 samples. As for peanuts, Between 50-100 with different sizes, condition and lighting is a good starting point. 
This might get a bit hard if the hard shell of the peanut has been removed. A Haar classifier looks for places where the contrast changes drastically, and a peanut without the shell won't have many unless it is split. Since haar classifiers operate on grayscale, you might want to use color to verify the results and remove false positives.

Comment: A big problem here is that peanuts are far more likely to be rotated than faces, when it comes to photos. You might have to rotate the photo and repeat detection a few times. 
If you have a fixed background, removing the background and analysing the remainder is a good plan.